# Is there any further significance to Russell's tattoo?

Tags: analysis, character, out-of-the-furnace

*Russell Baze*, the main protagonist of [*Out of the Furnace*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1206543/), has a quite prominent tattoo on his neck, which on a closer look seem to be the numbers **15104** or something similar:

[image]

While there might very well not be much more to this tattoo, it seemed too omnipresent to me during the whole movie to just be ignored as merely ornamental. **I thus wonder if there is any further significance to this tattoo that would tell us something more about his character.** Neither did the movie seem to give any explanation, but maybe I just don't have the necessary cultural background information, or it has been adressed in external interviews or the like.

Comment: Well, that certainly ruined my day. I didn't see the "4" so I researched "1510" and came up with a seriously cool connection to the ancient Greek word "eimi" which means "I am/I exist" in its basic form but also means "I exist outside of time". http://biblehub.com/greek/1510.htm Oh well. Maybe I'll just have to get my own cryptic tattoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the film's [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_Furnace):

> The Carrie Furnace, an abandoned blast furnace near Braddock, served as the location for the film's finale. **Christian Bale wore a tattoo of Braddock's ZIP code, 15104, on his neck** as an homage to the town's mayor John Fetterman, who has the same design on his arm.

[image]

Comment: Oh my, didn't bother to check Wikipedia for that, ashes to my head.